# Llevar datos de un SQLite a un TextView (Contenido en TableRow)

Tags: java, android

Buenas!, tengo una base de datos creada a partir de EditText, y esos datos quiero llevarlos a vistas de texto que están contenidos en TableRow, si me pueden ayudar a completar me ayudarían mucho, gracias!

Base de datos:

```
private String sql = "create table eventos(" +
        "idHorario int identity,"+
        "uno1 varchar(40)," +
        "uno2 varchar(40)," +
        "uno3 varchar(40)," +
        "uno4 varchar(40)," +
        "uno5 varchar(40)," +
        "dos1 varchar(40)," +
        "dos2 varchar(40)," +
        "dos3 varchar(40)," +
        "dos4 varchar(40)," +
        "dos5 varchar(40)," +
        "tres1 varchar(40)," +
        "tres2 varchar(40)," +
        "tres3 varchar(40)," +
        "tres4 varchar(40)," +
        "tres5 varchar(40)," +
        "cuatro1 varchar(40)," +
        "cuatro2 varchar(40)," +
        "cuatro3 varchar(40)," +
        "cuatro4 varchar(40)," +
        "cuatro5 varchar(40)," +
        "cinco1 varchar(40)," +
        "cinco2 varchar(40)," +
        "cinco3 varchar(40)," +
        "cinco4 varchar(40)," +
        "cinco5 varchar(40)," +
        "seis1 varchar(40)," +
        "seis2 varchar(40)," +
        "seis3 varchar(40)," +
        "seis4 varchar(40)," +
        "seis5 varchar(40)," +
        "siete1 varchar(40)," +
        "siete2 varchar(40)," +
        "siete3 varchar(40)," +
        "siete4 varchar(40)," +  "siete5 varchar(40))";

public BDSQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Clase horarios:

```
public class HORARIOActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horario);

    Button boton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.boton1);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HORARIOActivity.this, Editar.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


}
```

Layout tabla (que tiene textviews):

```
       <TextView
        Android:id=@+id/TXT1
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

entonces lo que busco es que los datos guardados en uno1, uno2, etc (inputs del usuario, en otra clase, y que luego son guardados en la base de datos) luego se puedan ver en TXT1 (ver id text view), en resumen, desplegar info de la base de datos al textview, gracias!

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT codigo,nombre FROM Usuarios WHERE nombre=? ", args);
```

o bien

```
Cursor c = db.query("Usuarios", campos, "usuario=?", args, null, null, null);
```

Y posteriormente puedes ejecutar consultas sobre el cursor.
como int id=c.getInt(0);